# How to use a variable in "Select [some calculations] insert into @NameOfTheTableInThisVariable"?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a procedure in which there are calculations being done and the final result is inserted into a permanent table. I want to remove the permanent table and I cannot use Temp table as well. So i want to use a dynamic table name, which is stored in a variable:

Current scenario:

```
Insert into xyz_table
    Select col1,col2,sum(col3)
    from BaseTable
```

(In reality, there are lot of columns and a lot of calculations)

What I want:

```
Select col1,col2,sum(col3) into @DynamicTableName
from BaseTable
```

where the name of the table would be dynamic in nature i.e.,

```
@DynamicTableName = 'xyz ' + cast(convert(date,getdate()) as nvarchar)+' '+convert(nvarchar(5),getdate(),108)
```

It will have date and time in its name every time the procedure is run.

I want to use this name in the "Select * into statement"

How can I achieve this?

i tried it with the some short code. But since my procedure has a lot of calculations and UNIONS , I cannot use that code for this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
declare @tablename nvarchar(30)= 'xyz ' + cast(convert(date,getdate()) as nvarchar)+' '+convert(nvarchar(5),getdate(),108)

declare @SQL_Statement  nvarchar(100)
declare @SQL_Statement2 nvarchar(100)
declare @dropstatement  nvarchar(100)

SET @SQL_Statement = N'SELECT * Into ' +'['+@tablename +'] '+'FROM '+ 'dimBranch'
print   @SQL_Statement
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL_Statement

SET     @SQL_Statement= N'select * from ' + '['+@tablename + '] '
print   @SQL_Statement
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL_Statement

set   @dropstatement = 'DROP TABLE' + '['+@tablename + '] '
PRINT @dropstatement
exec  sp_executesql @dropstatement
```

Reason why I want this is because I use this procedure in ETL job as well as in SSRS report. And if someone runs the package and the SSRS report at the same time, the incorrect or weird data gets stored in the table. Therefore I need a dynamic name of the table with date and time.

Comment: The only way you can achieve this is with dynamic SQL. If your query is "complex", then you'll need to make that complex query dynamic; ensuring that you properly quote your objects (`'['+@tablename + '] '` is not properly quoting, use `QUOTENAME`), and parametrise your SQL. [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql).

Comment: You do not need to stop and start your string all the time; it just makes things messy. `N'SELECT * Into ' +'['+@tablename +'] '+'FROM '+ 'dimBranch'` is exactly that same as `N'SELECT * Into ['+@tablename +'] FROM dimBranch'`

Comment: "But since my procedure has a lot of calculations and UNIONS , I cannot use that code for this." Why? `sp_executesql` accepts `nvarchar(max)` argument, 2GB text.

Answer (score 0):

You can't parameterize an identifier in SQL, only a value

```
--yes
select * from table where column = @value

--no
select * from @tablename where @columnname = @value
```

The only thin you can do to make these things dynamic is to build an sql string and execute it dynamically, but your code is already doing this with sp_executesql

More telling is your complaint at the bottom of your question, that if the procedure is invoked simultaneously it gives problems. Perhaps you should consider using local table variables for temporary data storage that the report is using rather than pushing data back into the db

```
    DECLARE @temp TABLE(id INT, name varchar100);
    INSERT INTO @temp SELECT personid, firstname FROM person;
    -- work with temp data
    select count(*) from @temp;

    --when @temp goes out of scope it is lost, 
    --no other procedure invoked simultaneously can access this procedure'a @temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a local temp table, which is automatically session scoped without the need for dynamic SQL. For example:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #YourTempTable
FROM dimBranch;
```

The local temp table will automatically be dropped when the proc completes so there is no need for an explict drop in the proc code.